# Linux "find" command and highlight filename

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am using the Linux `find` command.  It looks through all the `*.jar` files and their contents and finds the word "foo" in them but sometimes the filename might also contain the word "foo".  (ie. foo.jar, foo-123.jar, myfoo.jar, etc) If so, I would like to highlight the word "foo" in the filename.

I have 2 commands that works great on their own but is there a way I can combine them to one statement?

```
find . -type f -name *.jar | grep -E --color "foo" 
find . -type f -name *.jar -exec grep -li "foo" {} \;
```

Comment: If you mean dropping `grep` and just using `find` I doubt there's a way.

Comment: I understand that this doesn't work but something like this:

Comment: find /opt/ -type f -name *.jar | grep -E --color "foo" -exec grep -li "foo" {} \;

Comment: That's just nonsense. Code which doesn't do what you want is a poor way to indicate what you do want anyway. Can you [edit] to clarify what the result should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `-fprint` of `find` to write to a process substitution.

```
find . -type f -name \*.jar -fprint >(grep --color foo) -exec grep -li foo {} \;
```

Note: Quote arguments with globbing characters like `*`. Using the option `-E` is useless, if you search just for a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

To find those files which have the word *foo* in the content **and** in the file name, you could do a

```
find . -type f -name *.jar -exec grep -li "foo" {} \; | grep -Fi foo
```

The result of the -exec will print the names of all files which have *foo* in them, and the subsequent *grep* chooses from this files with *foo* in name.